# what does "?" mean in ${foo:?} in bash?

Tags: bash

I have some bash scripts which I am going through and I find that the code uses following construct for many variables:

```
ID1="{ID2:?}"

. ${PATH1:?}/file1
```

Can someone please help me in understanding what `?` does in this?

Comment: Are you sure the line defining `ID1` is correct here, ie. not missing a `$`? It would make more sense as `ID1="${ID2:?}"`; as it is, it's likely a bug.

Comment: (...btw, `?` can mean a lot of different things in a lot of different contexts even in the same language, which is why it's a good thing to make the title for the question specify the context; for instance, `${foo#?}` or `${foo%?}` would be something completely different, and `echo foo?` would have yet another meaning).

Answer (score 5):

In this context, it raises an error if the parameter is unset or null. Usually, you see a custom error message following the `?`, but in the absence of one, a generic error message is printed instead.

```
$ unset id2
$ id1=${id2:?}
bash: id2: parameter null or not set
$ id1=${id2:?nope}
bash: id2: nope
$ id2=9
$ id1=${id2:?}
$ echo $id1
9
```